# Is the concept of vector size something relative to the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ will always have this size: $\sqrt{1^2+0^2}=\sqrt{1}=1$. But given the basis $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, the coordinate vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ is pointing to the point $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ in the standard basis, so its size can also be calculated this way: $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$ , so maybe I'm making a silly mistake here but I can't find it out. Could a size such as $1$ in a vector space have a different value (e.g. $\sqrt{2}$) in another vector space? Is it illegal to interpret things in the standard space when we're in a different vector space?

Comment: You'll be interested to learn that there are [different definitions of "size"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space).

Comment: Anything that depends on the coordinates will depend on the basis.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll go through the Wikipedia article, but @Javi, could you make your point a bit clearer regarding to the example in my question? do you mean that coordinate vector is an inferior member of the world vectors? Maybe because it's in essence a tuple of scalars that we _interpret_ as a vector?

Comment: I mean that the coordinates of a vector depend on the choice of basis for the vector space because coordinates are just the scalars in the unique linear combination of the basis that gives you the vector. For something to be independent of the coordinates, it should also be independent of the basis (in this case, it should be that any basis has the same set of sizes, which is not the case). So in a sense, that tuple is indeed a representation of the vector and not the vector itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector doesn't *a priori* have a size. Abstractly, a vector $v$ is just an element of a vector space $V$, which is a set with some operations (addition, multiplication by a scalar) and rules about how those operations work (e.g. commutativity).

If you want to talk about vectors *with sizes*, you are talking about a *normed vector space*. A normed vector space is just a vector space $V$ with a function $\| \cdot \|_V$ defined on it, called the norm. For any vector $v \in V$, you get a real number $\| v \|_V$, and it is supposed to satisfy the following three rules:

- For any $v \in V$, $\|v\|_V \geq 0$.
- If $\|v\|_V = 0$, then $v = 0$.
- If $\alpha$ is any scalar, then $\|\alpha \cdot v\|_V = |\alpha|\cdot \|v\|_V$
- For any $v, w \in V$, $\|v + w\|_V \leq \|v\|_V + \|w\|_V$.

You already know about at least one norm: the standard Euclidean norm on the vector space $\mathbb R^2$, where
$$
\left\|\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\right\|_2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.
$$
(This 2 in the bottom specifies that this is the Euclidean norm you are talking about.)

You can check that this satisfies all the rules listed above. But you could define lots of other norms on the vector space $\mathbb R^2$; for example, $\|v\|_\infty = \max\{|v_1|, |v_2|\}$, or $\|v\|_{\text{skew}} = \sqrt{(v_1+v_2)^2 + v_1^2}$. In fact that last one is exactly the norm you have calculated by looking at your vectors in a different basis.

In general, if you have a change of basis, this will usually not preserve the norm. (In fact, changes of basis that preserve the norm are quite special.) That is, by changing the basis you get a *new* norm, and when specifying what you mean by "size" of your vector, you need to be clear about what norm you are using if it isn't clear from context.

Comment: So I guess it is **_wrong_** to say that the vector (1  0) will always have the size 1, yes? (Because, if I've understood your answer correctly, it depends on how the "size" have been defined in that vector space)(I'm considering the "size" and the "norm" as synonymous things here, let me know please if this is not the case).

Comment: Indeed the size of a vector depends on the norm under consideration. That said, it may be "clear from context" which norm is being used, even if it isn't necessarily clear to someone who is new to the subject. In particular, the Euclidean norm is the standard norm on $\mathbb R^2$ (and more generally $\mathbb R^n$), so if you are working with $\mathbb R^n$, and you are not considering any base changes, and it is not specified anywhere that you may be working with a different norm, it is usually fine to assume the norm to be the Euclidean one.

Comment: Ok, I've got this one, but I still don't know what specifically is wrong with the example I've given in my question(I know you have answered it so I accepted it, the fault is on me), I've not given the context for both so we can assume in both cases I have used the Euclidean norm, right? When you said "_if you have a change of basis, this will usually not preserve the norm_" did you mean I had a _fallacy_ in my question? I want to know what that fallacy is in my example specifically. (Is any of the two sizes 1 or $\sqrt{2}$ correct? Or both are wrong? Sorry I'm confused as hell:))

Comment: It seems to me that the argument you have put up for consideration is: we are looking at $\mathbb R^2$ with basis $\{(1\,1),(1\,0)\}$, and we have the coordinate vector $(1\,0)$. The size of the vector $(1\,0)$ is 1, but this "is also" the vector $(1\,1)$, whose size is $\sqrt{2}$, which is a problem since $1 \neq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: It is probably most sensible to say that the mistake is: when using a basis, typically the size of a coordinate vector is not equal to the size of the vector it represents. However it might be natural to say that the coordinate vector *is the same as* the vector it represents, just written down differently; in that case, the norm on the space of coordinate vectors should not be the standard Euclidean norm.

Comment: Wow... I think it just clicked for me so well :) Yes, now I can see why the coordinate vector in the new basis should not be able to use the Euclidean norm, its elements are not equi-weighed, while the Euclidean norm works based on the Pythagorean relation on a right isosceles triangle, while in this new basis we will have non-right & non-isosceles triangles. So all in all, the gist of it is just as you said: "In general, if you have a change of basis, this will usually not preserve the norm." and as @Javi said: "Anything that depends on the coordinates will depend on the basis.". Thank you.